# Modifying or adding new tags to a jpg (Metadata) with iim4j

Tags: java, tags, metadata, jpeg, keyword

I am trying to modify or add new tags with the iim4j library, but its documentation is poor. I've been searching for examples on the internet and didn't found anything so far. I only got the examples the library offers. There's one example about reading the Metadata and I can get the title, description and tags of the image (the ones I care). I know the library manage these info as DataSet and DataSetInfo so I tried to create new instances of these objects for the info I want to add but I have no results so far.

This is the code for reading the IPTC section of a jpeg file:

```
    public static void dump(File file) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("IPTC segment for " + file);
    IIMFile iimFile = new IIMFile();

    IIMReader reader = new IIMReader(new JPEGIIMInputStream(new FileIIMInputStream(file)), new IIMDataSetInfoFactory());
    iimFile.readFrom(reader, 20);

    for (Iterator i = iimFile.getDataSets().iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        DataSet ds = (DataSet) i.next();            
        Object value = ds.getValue();
        if (value instanceof byte[]) {
            value = "<bytes " + ((byte[]) value).length + ">";
        }
        DataSetInfo info = ds.getInfo();
        if (info instanceof DefaultDataSetInfo)
        {
            System.out.println("-----------");
            System.out.println("Number : " + info.getDataSetNumber());
            System.out.println("Name :" + info.getName());
            Serializer serializador=info.getSerializer();
            if(serializador instanceof StringSerializer)
                System.out.println("Serializer :" + serializador.toString());
            System.out.println("Repeat : " + info.isRepeatable());
            System.out.println("----------");
        }

        System.out.println(info.toString() + " " + info.getName() + ": " + value);

    }
    reader.close();
}
```

I can obtain all the info I need and also I know that kind of objects I must use to add new info on another files. So i tried this one to add a new tag:

```
    String tagToAdd="Tag to add";
    int size= tagToAdd.length();
    DefaultDataSetInfo valueTag=new DefaultDataSetInfo(537,"Keywords", new StringSerializer(size+ ""),true);
    DefaultDataSet dataSet=new DefaultDataSet(valueTag, tagToAdd.getBytes());
    iimFile.add(dataSet);
```

and tried this one to write a new file with a tag:

```
    String tagToAdd="Tag to add";
    int size= tagToAdd.length();
    DefaultDataSetInfo valueTag=new DefaultDataSetInfo(537,"Keywords", new StringSerializer(size+ ""),true);
    DefaultDataSet dataSet=new DefaultDataSet(valueTag, tagToAdd.getBytes());

    IIMWriter escritor= new IIMWriter(new DefaultIIMOutputStream(file));
    escritor.write(dataSet);
    escritor.close();
```

Tags weren't add. I need some help with this library and its use. Thanks

Comment: As you say, the documentation is poor, which is a real shame because from what I have seen the code is not. In fact, after having to wrestle with commons-imaging iim4j looks stellar. Also, see my answer for a simple solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

From my own testing, it seems that `IIMWriter` is only intended to be used to write the IPTC metadata to a file, and nothing else. Needless to say, that does not make for a valid JPEG file. What you want is to take an existing JPEG file, and generate a new file with the same data, except for the IPTC metadata that should be removed (if any) and replaced with the content of your `IIMFile`.

That's exactly what `JPEGUtil.insertIIMIntoJPEG` is for. What you need to do is something like this (where `newFile` is a `File` insatnce pointing to where you want to save the modified JPEG):

```
// 1. Read original IIM
IIMReader reader = new IIMReader(new JPEGIIMInputStream(new FileIIMInputStream(file)), new IIMDataSetInfoFactory());
iimFile.readFrom(reader, 20);

// 2. Add dataset
DataSet dataSet = ... // Whatever you want
iimFile.add(dataSet);

// 3. Create new copy of JPEG file new IIM
try (
  InpuStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
  OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(newFile))
) {
  JPEGUtil.insertIIMIntoJPEG(out, iimFile, in)
}
```